# Javascript ScrollTo does not work on page load

Tags: javascript

I have a issue, I want to scroll the page to a particular element once the page renders by calling window.scrollTo(). But doesn't work. Any limitations?

```
var step = Math.round(distance / 25); // distance is Stop-start
  var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
    var timer = 0;
    if (stopY > startY) {
        for (var i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
            setTimeout(window.scrollTo(0,leapY), timer * speed);
            leapY += step;
            if (leapY > stopY) 
                leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
setTimeout(window.scrollTo(0,leapY), timer * speed);
```

calls `window.scrollTo` **immediately** and passes its return value into `setTimeout`, just like `foo(bar())` calls `bar` **immediately** and passes its return value into `foo`.

You need to pass in a function:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0,leapY); }, timer * speed);
```

But that alone isn't enough, because the function will look at the `leapY` value as it is *when it runs*, not when it's defined, and so they'll all end up using the last value of `leapY`. So you want a builder function:

```
setTimeout(buildScroller(leapY), timer * speed);

function buildScroller(y) {
    return function() { window.scrollTo(0,y); };
}
```

In the loop, we call the builder passing in `leapY` as the `y` argument, and it returns a function closing over the argument (rather than `leapY`). That argument doesn't change, so the function it builds uses the right value.

---

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/anibod/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/anibod/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Scrolling On Load In Loop</title>
  <style>
    div {
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Scrolls to each of the first four followingdivs at intervals of one second</div>
  <div>0x100</div>
  <div>0x200</div>
  <div>0x300</div>
  <div>0x400</div>
  <div>0x500</div>
  <div>0x600</div>
  <div>0x700</div>
  <div>0x800</div>
  <div>0x900</div>
  <div>0x1000</div>
  <div>0x1100</div>
  <div>0x1200</div>
  <div>0x1300</div>
  <div>0x1400</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var leapY;

      for (leapY = 1; leapY <= 4; ++leapY) {
        setTimeout(buildScroller(leapY * 200), leapY * 1000);
      }

      function buildScroller(y) {
          return function() { window.scrollTo(0,y); };
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RavitejaAvvari: That would suggest problems elsewhere. For instance, with the units you're giving to `scrollTo`, or with not having enough content for the window to scroll down that far (it won't scroll such that the *end* of your content is above the bottom of the window). The above works, I've added a live example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I thoroughly checked the code and could Identify that there is a overflow-y:auto for the html element in the page which is preventing scroll to happen. Thank you for the efforts and patience to help me. Appreciable.

Comment: @RavitejaAvvari: Ah! That would do it. :-) Glad you figured it out. Best,